# Remove Search.bitcro.com virus from google chrome in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, malware, antivirus

Google chrome redirect to other links when I search in google. `Search.bitcro.com` seems to be a browser hijacker. I have seen many solutions to solve it in windows but none in ubuntu. How do I remove it and make my system secure? How do I prevent it from affecting again?

`ubuntu 12.04`, `google chrome`

Comment: Have you tried to reset browser's setting to default?

Comment: @snoop ohh ... let me try to reset. But do i need to worry about any thing else ?

Comment: Yes, all your profile data will be deleted if you reset your browser's settings.

Comment: @snoop yeaa thtz ok.....but i was asking about the security.

Comment: @snoop . Wht do i need to do in my system to prevent such malwares ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a browser hijacker, to get rid of it you can：
1.Reset browser settings

2.Disable/Remove Chrome extensions

If it does not go away, then you need the third step,

3.Download [removal tool](http://blog.trymytools.com/how-to-remove-search-bitcro-com-from-your-browser/) and run it

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are or were infected on a Windows Machine and your Chrome on the Ubuntu machine just synchronized preferences and bookmarks into it, changing your setting on both, if this is the case make sure you have completely removed the infection on the Win machine first or if you logged on Another computer with that account change your @gmail password using another browser such as Midori.
If you don't have Midori

```
sudo apt-get install midori
```

After that try the following:

Clear your profile

`killall chrome`

`rm -Rf .config/google-chrome/`

- Open Chrome and test without synchronizing.

Comment: i don't use windows anymore. I quit it an year ago. It definitely got affected while using in ubuntu.

Comment: No virtual machines ? or logins from a friend, relative ... computer running Windows?

Comment: well.....that might have happened. So are u saying tht there is little chance that it gets affected while in Ubuntu ?

Comment: I truly don't believe you are infected, I think your browser is carrying over settings from an infected machine or virtual machine, that's all.

Comment: @it is solved after resetting google chrome. That might be true since i have logined few times from some other windows systems. But this thing started appearing while using in Ubuntu.